# Finding if a function with cases is differntiable on a point

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-verification

> Is $g$ differentiable on $x=0$ ?
>
> $$g(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{e^x-1}{x}&,x\neq0 \\ 1 &,x=0  \end{cases} $$

The derivative for $x\neq0$: $g'(x)=\dfrac{e^x(x-1)+1}{x^2}$, by taking the limit of $g'$ from both sides of 0 I get $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0\pm}\frac {e^x}{2}=\frac 1 2$.

Now trying to use the definition of a derivative with $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ to get to the same value with $x=0$:

$\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {g(h)-g(0)}{h}=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h}-1} {h^2}=\text{(LHR twice)}=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h}} {2h}=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h}} {2}=
(h\to0)=
\frac{e^{0}}{2}=
\frac 1 {2}$

So does that mean that it's differentiable on $x=0$ ?

Is this the general approach for finding out if a function is differentiable on a point ?

Comment: You basically check if $g'$ is continous at $x = 0$.

Comment: Right, makes sense.

Comment: Your idea of using L'Hospital's Rule twice is good. There is a mistake in the algebra.

Comment: I get $\frac{\mathrm{e}^{h}-h-1}{h^2}$, yielding $\frac{1}{2}$.  (Replicated your typo the first time I checked this.  Fixed now.)

Comment: @EricTowers see my edit, where's the error ?

Comment: Why do you get $e^{h-1}$?

Comment: at $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{h-1}-1}{h^2}$.  In particular, $g(h) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^h-1}{h}$ does not contain an exponent of $h-1$.

Comment: @EricTowers what do you mean by does not contain ?

Comment: Do you see "h-1" as an exponent in $g(h)$?

Comment: I don't understand, you mean $(h-1)^2$ ?

Comment: @EricTowers, ok edited, the derivative of $e^{x-1}$ is itself. I still don't get 1/2.

Comment: Look at the first step of $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}$ again. $g(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$, so $g(h)=\frac{e^h-1}{h}$. Compare that with your calculations above.

Comment: @ChrisBln oh I get it. lol

Comment: @GinKin:  Using your definition of $g$, write down $g(h)$.  If you have an exponent of "h-1", you are wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice that. Thanks guys. Edited now.

Comment: Sorry, your calculations are still wrong. Compare with those in the answer of André Nicolas.

Comment: @ChrisBln yup that was another error I made, I tried to input $0$ in the function and got 0/0 so I ignored that and regarded it as 0. It's ironic I still got the same answer because of LHR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you started to do in the post, we check differentiability at $0$ by using the definition. So we want to find whether 
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{e^h-1}{h}-1}{h}$$
exists. Minor manipulation transforms this to 
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{e^h-1-h}{h^2}.$$
Now using L'Hospital's Rule twice finishes things. The derivative at $0$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

**Remarks:** $1.$ the original algebraic glitch in the OP has now been corrected. As to the question about whether the method is the general approach, there are many approaches. But writing down an explicit expression for $\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}$ and finding the limit of this (if it exists) is certainly the most fundamental approach, but once we have developed some machinery, many approaches become available.

$2.$ More easily, if one is comfortable with series, write down the power series for $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$. We get a nice expression, and in fact the given function is infinitely differentiable everywhere.

Comment: Why is $g(0)=1$ ? edit: oh because that is how it's defined in the cases right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I just wrote down $\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}$.

Answer (score 1):

I gave a very similar question in an exam. The derivative from the left
$$ g'(0-)= \frac{1}{2} $$
is correct and in order of the function to be differentiable you need to demand that the left derivative equals to the derivative from the right. In your case,
$$ g'(0+) = \frac{1}{2} $$
as well.

It is easy to see that $g$ is continuous 
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1 = g(0) . $$

Now use Taylor expansion
$$ e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^3) $$ to get that
$$ g(x) = \frac{ 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^3) - 1}{x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} + o(x^2) $$
so $g$ is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: But with that you get that $g(0)=1\neq \frac 1 2$